# android can not find a class 'javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap', but that class is in the jre libs locates at rt.jar

Tags: android

In my android project, I use a external jar which will use the class

Here is the error information:

06-13 02:45:18.586: ERROR/dalvikvm(228): Could not find class `'javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap', referenced from method weibo4j.http.HttpClient.multPartURL`

Who can tell me why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javax.activation` package is not part of the [Android core](http://developer.android.com/reference/) (as you can see, it's not in the package index), so you will not be able to use that Jar without a recompiled `javax.activation` jar (if there is one at all). What does this external Jar do?

Comment: Thank you very much, i use a sdk which references that jar, but that sdk is a java-sdk. 'javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap' is in the 'rt.jar' which locates at the lib of jre6, how can i recompile that jar?

Comment: [This project](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/) might help you out. Check out their downloads section. Note, however, that if the class is not originally included in the Android SDK it is for a good reason, and you might want to consider a more standard Android approach for whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ext= MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri)
```

By this you can get extension of file and then compare with different `mimetype`